# Connect Azure DevOps Queries to SharePoint List using Power Automate

Tags: azure-devops, sharepoint, power-automate

I want to connect "Queries" option from azure devops to my sharepoint list using power automate.

[image: Link to the screenshot/ picture]

I have a custom query in the "queries" option in azure devops that has data.

How can I transfer that data into sharepoint list using power automate?

Comment: I can't help but ask why? Other questions to help answer your question: Is this a one time run - or - will be run multiple times which will "sync" work items to SP list items?

Comment: Its not work items. Its Azure Dev Ops Queries. There I have a custom query which will be the input. It will be a scheduled flow which will run every hour. I do not want to connect "work item" from azure dev ops to sharepoint list. That is achievable.

Comment: What does the query return? A list of...? Power Automate has a "Get query results" under Azure Devops connector. Where are you needing help?

Comment: Well I have found a way to do it and I have created a power automate work flow related to that.

Comment: Hi @Runtime21, Have you got a chance to check my answer below? If you have figured out a better workflow, could you please also post your answer? It will help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Comment: @AlvinZhao my flow is very much similar to yours. It works. I had a different curious question if you have any idea do let me know. I posted the question on the community. Link: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Exclude-data-based-on-certain-columns-from-source-in-power/m-p/2416806#M269525

Comment: Hi @Runtime21, I checked the other post of yours. From the perspective of Azure DevOps, I think you may add new clause to filter out the unexpected work items rather than eliminate them via Power Automate action. For the topic we discussed here, would you consider marking the answer, which may benefit others with similar conerns. Thx.

Comment: Cools thanks for the input.

Comment: Hi @Runtime21, You may consider [marking the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), so that other users who have similar requirements may benefit. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @Sam Nseir mentioned, the action of `Get query results` under Azure Devops connector can help get the query results in Azure DevOps. Then, you may consider to `Create item` in SharePoint list with the results. However, once the query results changed, to synchronize the update into SharePoint list will be difficult.

For this, I generated a simple workflow for your reference.

[image]

1. Get all items in the SharePoint list;
   [image]
2. Delete all the items in the list;
   [image]
3. Get query results from Azure DevOps;
   [image]
4. Create new items into the list with each work item from the query result;
   [image]

Kindly note that the item `ID` will be changed after each re-creation. You may consider using a custom column in the SharePoint list to identify each work item from the query result. Hope the sample could help.